# How to use json data from from a php file in a ajax function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make a login page that validates the users input data. If "username" and "password" does not match in the database he would receive a warning.
I'm a total newbie when it comes to this, so the code I have now is a combination of different tutorials.

my signin.php looks like this:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json')

$data = array();    // array to pass back data

if(!empty($_POST["action"]))
{
    if($_POST["action"] == "signin")
    {
       ...all the SQL code here...

        if(!empty($result))
        {
            foreach ($result as $row)
            {
                ...some SQL code here...

                $data["success"] = true;
                $data["message"]  = "Success!";                                       
            }            
        }
        else
        {
            $data["success"] = false;
            $data["message"]  = "Error!";
        }        
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
}
```

Now I want this json data to be used in a jquery submit function that uses ajax to get the data from signin.php:

```
<script>
    $("#login-form").submit(function(event) {
        $.ajax({
            type        : 'POST',
            url         : 'signin.php', 
            data        : { 'action': 'signin' },
            dataType    : 'json'
        }).done(function(data) {
            console.log(data.success);
            if(!data.success)
            {
                alert("ERROR");
            }
            else if (data.success)
            {
                alert("SUCCESS");
            }
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: [Don't limit passwords](http://jayblanchard.net/security_fail_passwords.html)  and [use the proper methods to hash passwords with PHP](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html).

Comment: use `console.log(data)` so you can see the structure of the entire object.  I'm pretty sure you should be `data['success']` not `data.success`.  Running the console log on the entire object should help you clear that up.

Comment: console.log(data) gives me nothing

Comment: I'd suggest using the developer tools like Firebug to investigate. There should be a response received from the Ajax call, and this should show up in the network tab.

Comment: @Jeppe What is it your looking for exactly?  Do you have the sql code or is that what you need?  Looking at your code again data returns nothing because your php code isn't doing anything.  Also your not passing any data except action='signin' through the ajax function.  Your php code is never getting any of the login data form the form because it's not being passed.  using jQuery's `$('#formID').serialize()` would work for that.

Comment: Yes I know my problem is getting the right data passed, but I have no idea what I'm doing anymore.
I want the input data to be validated in my signin.php and it would respond with a json array

Comment: Then you should first add debug code to verify you get the correct data you expect. `var_dump($_POST); die()` would be in order - send the data, and use Firebug to see what has been returned. It won't work with the javascript which is meant to process the return values, it is meant to get the sending of the form data right on the Javascript side. Once that POST array has the data you expect, remove the debug code and see if it works. It doesn't look too bad for my eyes.

Comment: It is working, but I'm trying to figure out how to pass a message to the user if his input is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for the responds, I figured out the problem